# List PyPI packages by popularity

Tags: python, pypi

Is it possible to obtain a list of PyPI packages ordered by popularity (number of total downloads)?

I am unable to find a way to do this on PyPI. Perhaps PyPI provides a database dump for this purpose?

If I'm unable to find a simpler way, I plan to scrape PyPI using their JSON API.

Comment: I think the question is not about recommendation, but statistics...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Python Wheels](https://pythonwheels.com) site lists the top 360 most-downloaded packages on PyPI showing which have been uploaded as wheel archives.

https://pythonwheels.com

Comment: For Python3 packages check this out: http://py3readiness.org/

Comment: @Kubas The website is no longer available.

Answer (score 8):

[Top PyPI Packages](https://hugovk.github.io/top-pypi-packages/) is a weekly JSON dump of the 4,000 most-downloaded packages from PyPI, one for the last 30 days, and another for the last 365 days.

It uses [pypinfo](https://github.com/ofek/pypinfo) to fetch PyPI download stats from Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://pypi-ranking.info/ is currently down.

Another useful website is http://pythonwheels.com/. It shows the top 360 most-downloaded packages on PyPI. I believe the bar on the right lists these packages in order. Green packages are those that support wheels. White packages are those that don't (yet).

Answer (score 1):

PyPI download logs since October 2016 can be analyzed in great detail at [BigQuery](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/the-psf:pypi?pli=1). Here's an [example query](https://gist.github.com/alex/4f100a9592b05e9b4d63) to get the most downloaded packages, but many other dimensions are also available.

[Background information](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2016-May/028986.html) (may be somewhat out of date).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://nullege.com ?
It's a search engine for python packages, contains also examples.
Cheers.

Comment: Seems that died in 2018. When I wrote answer was up and running. Check wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180814112714/http://nullege.com/ . Also, on quick search on google is used by some github projs.

Comment: It is up as of 2021.