# List popular version of a PyPI package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

Is it possible to get the popular version of a PyPI package and also if possible list of different versions of a package in terms of number of downloads? I have read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020861/list-pypi-packages-by-popularity) but I am looking for different versions of a package.

Comment: [Analyzing PyPI package downloads using Google BigQuery](https://packaging.python.org/guides/analyzing-pypi-package-downloads/).